# Inferring return type of templated member functions in CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp, c++14

**Is it possible to infer the return type of a templated member function in a CRTP base class?**

While inferring argument types works well, it fails with the return type. Consider the example below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
  template <typename R, typename T>
  R f(T x)
  {
    return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).f_impl(x);
  }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
  bool f_impl(int x)
  {
    std::cout << "f(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
};

int main()
{
  bool b = derived{}.f(42);
  return b ? 0 : 1;
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
  bool b = derived{}.f(42);
           ~~~~~~~~~~^
crtp.cc:7:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'R'
  R f(T x)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

My intuitive assumption is that if the compiler is capable of inferring type `int` for the argument to `f`, it should also work for the return `bool`, because both types are known at template instantiation time.

I tried using the trailing return type function syntax, but then failed to find a working expression to put in `decltype`.

### EDIT 1

For the case where the function has one or more templated arguments, Dietmar Kühl provided a solution based on delaying template instantiation using on layer of indirection. Unfotunately, this does not work when a base class function does not have any argument, like this:

```
template <typename R>
R g()
{
  return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).g_impl();
}
```

Attempts to use the same technique fail because there exist no dependent types. How does one handle this case?

### EDIT 2

As pointed out by Johannes Schaub, C++11 features default template arguments, so it is always possible to make `g` dependent on an arbitrary type and then apply Dietmar's solution:

```
template <typename T = void>
auto g() -> typename g_impl_result<Derived, T>::type
{
  return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).g_impl();
}
```

### EDIT 3

This problem does not exist in C++14 anymore, since we have return type deduction for normal functions, allowing us to write simply:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
  template <typename T>
  auto f(T x)
  {
    return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).f_impl(x);
  }

  auto g()
  {
    return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).g_impl();
  }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
  bool f_impl(int x)
  {
    return true;
  }

  double g_impl()
  {
    return 4.2;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An extra indirection is your friend:

```
template <typename D, typename T>
struct f_impl_result
{
    typedef decltype(static_cast<D*>(0)->f_impl(std::declval<T>())) type;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T x) -> typename f_impl_result<Derived, T>::type
    {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).f_impl(x);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason you used the old `((D*)0)->foo()` trick to `declval`?

Comment: @RedXIII: no. I should have used `std::declval<D>()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Why is it impossible to declare the return type directly in `base`?

Comment: +1 for a working solution to the problem, but why is this indirection necessary, as @Walter points out? Is it generally impossible to find a direct solution inside the base class?

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: The problem is that the return type doesn't depend on `T` when specified directly and it is, thus, looked up when `base` gets instantiated as the base class of `derived`. At that point `derived` is incomplete. Depending on `T` delays instantiation until the first use of `T`, i.e., a call to `f()`, at which point `derived` is defined. I think. ... and there may be better ways to achieve that!

Comment: I see now what you're doing. Unfortunately this limits this technique to functions with template arguments. For example, it doesn't work for a function `auto g() -> typename g_impl_result<Derived>::type` because there exists no explicit dependent type in `g()` as template parameter.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin fortunately C++11 has default template arguments so you can always add `template<typename T = void>`.

Comment: I tried this but the f_impl function must be public in order for it to compile.