# Trailing return type usage when using CRTP

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, crtp, trailing-return-type

The following is a mockup code that I wrote to experiment with trailing return types in a CRTP setup.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct t_aspect{
    struct t_param1 {};
};

// Generic Selector
template <typename t_detail>
struct Select;

template <>
struct Select<t_aspect::t_param1> {
    using typeof = t_aspect::t_param1;
};

//Base CRTP class
template<typename dclas>
class CrtpB
{
    public:
        template<typename T1>
        auto func1() -> // What should be here?
        {
            return(static_cast<dclas*>(this)->func1<T1>());
        }
};


//Derived CRTP class
class CrtpD : public CrtpB<CrtpD>
{
    private:
        uint32_t param1 = 0;

    private:
        auto func1(const t_aspect::t_param1&) -> uint32_t
        {
            return(param1);
        }

    public:
        static auto create() -> unique_ptr<CrtpB>
        {
            return(unique_ptr<CrtpD>(new CrtpD));
        }

        template<typename T1>
        auto func1() -> decltype(func1(typename Select<T1>::typeof()))
        {
            return(func1(typename Select<T1>::typeof()));
        }
};


int main()
{
    auto crtp = CrtpD::create();
    auto parm = crtp->func1<t_aspect::t_param1>();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like some help in deciphering what should be the trailing return type of func1 in CrtpB.

I have tried using

```
decltype(static_cast<dclas*>(this)->func1<T1>())
```

but this does not work. I have also tried writing a helper function based on a solution found in [Inferring return type of templated member functions in CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392225/inferring-return-type-of-templated-member-functions-in-crtp).

```
template <typename D, typename T>
struct Helpr {
    typedef decltype(static_cast<D*>(0)->func1<T>()) type;
};
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dclas` is an incomplete type when the base class is instantiated. You need to do two things to make this work:

- Defer the checking of the type of `func1<T1>()` until the type is complete
- Use the `template` keyword on the dependent expression so that the template definition is parsed correctly:

We can do this by adding a layer of indirection:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class T, class Func1Arg>
    struct func1_t {
         using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().template func1<Func1Arg>());
    };
};
```

Then you use this trait as the trailing return type:

```
template<typename T1>
auto func1() -> typename detail::func1_t<dclas,T1>::type
{
    return(static_cast<dclas*>(this)->template func1<T1>());
}
```

Comment: When I compile the code with your fix in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com, the code compiles. I tried it on my machine and I get the following error: 

     snip1.cpp:33:34: error: static_cast from 'CrtpB<CrtpD> *' to 'CrtpD *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
        auto func2() -> decltype(static_cast<dclas*>(this)->template func2<T1>())

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @TartanLlama, I tried your previous suggestion and it does not seem to help. The error now is: 

snip1.cpp:34:62: error: no member named 'func2' in 'CrtpD'
        auto func2() -> decltype(declval<dclas*>()->template func2<T1>())

Comment: Yes this works !!! Thanks. It is very puzzling though why different compilers handle incomplete types in different ways.