# CRTP and method returning void *

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, crtp

I use C++ 11. I have a `Base` class and several derived classes for parsing different configuration files line by line.

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    bool load_from_file(const QString& str);
    virtual void* get_data(const QString& str) const  = 0;

private:
    QList<QSharedPointer<T> > items_;
};
```

Each descendant (`class Derived: public Base<My_struct>`) must provide `get_data()` implementation.
Each `My_struct` instance contains information from certain line of a settings file.

For example, imagine a typical file with a list of proxies.
`My_struct` instances are wrapped in smart pointers in `Base` class in the `load_from_file()` method and appended to the `items_` member. `load_from_file()` method casts `void*` to `T*` before wrapping.

Is it possible to redesign these classes in order to avoid using `void*` (and without libraries like `boost::any`)?
I mean considering CRTP and so on. Usually CRTP examples contain methods of derived classes with `void` return values (like procedures in Pascal).

Comment: What type do you actually want `get_data` to return? `My_struct`?

Comment: CRTP is `class Derived: public Base<Derived>`, not some other struct. Then you can make the function return `T *`.

Comment: @MarkRansom,  I'd like to return My_struct* in one of the derived classes

Answer (score 1):

Bro! Try to switch to C++14 and use the following snippet as a hint:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
 template <typename T>
 auto f(T x)
 {
  return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).f_impl(x);
 }

 auto g()
 {
  return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).g_impl();
 }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
 bool f_impl(int x)
 {
  return true;
 }

 double g_impl()
 {
  return 4.2;
 }
};
```

This fragment has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392225/inferring-return-type-of-templated-member-functions-in-crtp?rq=1).